# Post thumbnails not showing on facebook despite correct size.

Tags: facebook, wordpress, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

Hello dear Stack overflow community. I am desperate to solve this issue and really hope any of you can kindly assist me.

I have this piece of code on my Header.php to tell facebook to display my featured image thumbnail when sharing my links. I also have all my Open graph tags set.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
if( has_post_thumbnail( $thePostID )){
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $thePostID );
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id );
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$image[0].'" />';
} ?>
```

I have confirmed in my browser that the code is rendering correctly and that it's pointing to the appropriate thumbnail file. The file is 300x300 so it should be right.

Well, IT ISN'T!

When I pass my url through the facebook debugger it shows two fatal mistakes. One, it doesn't even display the correct image! Every single link I put through the debugger shows the same featured image. why is it ignoring the featured image of each post?

And it also says my images are not complaint with their minimum size requirements (200x200)

The images are 300x300!!! Why is it saying that!?

My website is www.estamosobservando.com if anybody wants to pass it through the debugger.

You will have my eternal gratitude if you can help me win this battle against Opengraph, Facebook and the world!

B.

Comment: I encountered the same problem before then I tried to move the image to the root directory. So the og:image pointed to domain.com/image.jpg and it worked fine. Maybe you could start from there.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The image referenced in the og:image tag is displaying correctly. The problem is with the featured image of each post... is there any away of changing the name and/or location of each of these images?

Comment: My biggest question of all is... why on earth is the debugger showing me an unrelated thumbnail, when the code renders the correct featured image for each post?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed this... Maybe this will help other users with the same problem... The reason it was using the same thumbnail in every link despite rendering the correct image in the source code is because of the

`<meta property="og:url" content="` line.

I entered there the URL of the site and of course, the canonical URL ruled them all, and the debugger went there to fetch the featured image. I replaced that value with

`<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>`

And that did it. Thank you for your kind help I hope this question helps others solve similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try Facebook developer debugger. It worked for me - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score -1):

The HTML for http://estamosobservando.com/ has two og:image tags in its header: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://estamosobservando.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/servicios-publicos-bogota-concept-art-150x150.jpg" />` and `<meta property="og:image" content="http://estamosobservando.com/wp-content/themes/servicios/images/ogtag-2013.jpg" />`.

Because all of the pages on your website use the same og:url tag, any page that a user shares on your website will share the homepage instead. While Facebook generally offers users a choice between images when posting, Facebook "freezes" some of the metadata after a URL has been shared a few times. This might be why only the generic image is appearing.

If you want users to be able to share individual posts, you should modify the lower OpenGraph tags to represent [individual articles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#article) instead of the [film website as a whole](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#movie).

Comment: Hello Martey how are you? Well, the first Meta Property corresponds to the featured image of each post. The second one corresponds to the image defined for the entire site. Isn't that the way it should be? The First tag is generated by the code I posted in my question. Any thoughts about what should I do?

Comment: And do you know why the facebook debugger is ignoring the first Meta Property and always displays the same thumbnail for every post?

Comment: Thank you Martey for you kind help. I just read the Facebook guidelines, but am a bit confused. In a wordpress site the header is the same throughout the whole site. How can I change the tags for each and every post?

Comment: Is there any function where I can specifically determine (with Url) the featured image for each post? Could that be a solution for this?

Comment: I've noticed something else... The debugger keeps fetching the wrong og:tag image. It retrieves Meta Tag:<meta property="og:image" content="http://estamosobservando.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/servicios-publicos-bogota-concept-art-150x150.jpg" /> 

ignoring that the 

<?php
global $wp_query; ....

code in the header is assigning the featured image of each post. Why does it keep doing this? When you look at the source code generated you can read it does point to the right image. ?????!!!!

Comment: Ok I fixed this... Maybe this will help other users with the same problem...

The reason it was using the same thumbnail in every link despite rendering the correct image in the source code is because of the <meta property="og:url" content=" line. I entered there the URL of the site and of course, the canonical URL ruled them all, and the debugger went there to fetch the featured image. I replaced that value with <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>

And that did it. 

Thank you for your kind help I hope this question helps others solve similar issues.